# Sendy External SMTP Bounce Handler

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-ses, sendy

Sendy will not track bounced email address when sending emails via any SMTP server. It only works when if you hook it with AWS SES.

As I'm using SMTP which is hosted on a Linux server along with IMAP, POP3. 
[image]

I sent thousands of mail using that SMTP and Sendy is not counting Bounced addresses while I checked my mailbox and there was thousands of undelivered mail.

[image]

Is there any way to make it count for Sendy SMTP?

I saw this image in Google, Don't know how to make it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The image you found does not appear to be part of Sendy -- it appears to be from [this](https://www.installsoftwaresupport.com/sendy-smtp-bounce-handler/) third party product.  It's not entirely clear.

What it seems to do is connect to your mailbox (the one you showed, with the bounces) using the POP3 mail fetching protocol... and read those bounce messages.

The web site seems to imply that this vendor wants access to your server and will install their products for you, which seems like a very dubious practice, so proceed with caution.

Comment: Yeah I saw that. So basically no option to make it working in SMTP?